# Rails ids returning more records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ids

I don't know if someone has had this issue:

When I do `Question.count` it returns **3112**, but when I run `Question.ids.count` the result is **9685**.

Is my database broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems when you include children in your query, also those ids are coming with the results. I had `default_scope { includes(:choices) }`, I removed it and everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah if you just google "Rails default_scope" you'll get a pretty clear picture of how the community feels about this "feature": https://andycroll.com/ruby/dont-use-default-scope/ https://www.lewuathe.com/why-we-should-avoid-default_scope-in-rails.html https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/rails/best-practices/why-using-default-scope-is-a-bad-idea.html https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/17746/beware-of--default-scope https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/

Comment: Indeed, I just removed that scope from every single model in my App, my bad! Thanks for the links.